# Could I verify text in image using Selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-rc

I have an app very similar to Google/Yahoo map.
I search for a location and it is displayed on map.
When I see html of page, there are many segments and all of them are images. I wonder if there is any way to verify that text for searched location is available on page.

For example if I search

http://maps.yahoo.com/#mvt=m&lat=36.298746&lon=-115.139974&zoom=12&q1=las%20vegas

There would be "Las Vegas" displayed on page. Now how do I verify that "Las Vegas" is really displayed on page?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So you want to check that the text in the image with selenium.
You will need to grab the url of the image, download that image, and put it through an OCR program.

So short answer, not with selenium

Comment: Thanks, I would look in to OCR, given the flexibility of languages in client libraries with Selenium. I hope I would be able to use one in java and integrate with Selenium test.

Comment: maps look really really tricky for this, a plain image would have been ok though....

Comment: actually it depends how much you want to check this? If its just one check per test or even a couple.. it might be worth just grabbing a screenshot of the page with selenium and checking them manually.... Or comparing against a verified image

Comment: I actually tried OCR but the characters I got to see were #$%^%&%^&$^*@#$. My next would be image comparison. Some times ago I read about checksum for image comparison. Goota try my hands though.

Answer (score 3):

Sikuli allows verification of images, or parts of images.  I've not tried it, or tried to integrate it with Selenium, but the concepts of what Sikuli can do, looks really good.  Take a look at the project here: http://sikuli.org/

Answer (score 0):

Actually I threat this here:

1. Shows you how you can compare 2 images and get a differences image or a gif animation with the overlapping of the first 2:

http://testautomationexperiences.com/detect-layout-issues-using-file-hashes-and-imagemagick-for-compare/

2. Do it in Selenium by using im4java and imagemagick; also the hash checking is the first step in verification:

http://testautomationexperiences.com/detect-layout-issues-using-file-hashes-and-imagemagick-for-compare-coding-in-java/

I hope it helps, even is not OCR.

For OCR, you need a library (created by you or an existing one) which you call from selenium.

Good luck,
Claudiu Adam

http://testautomationexperiences.com/